# Side-Drawer for the kitchen

Tags: kitchens, drawers

I have some space left under my kitchen sink, which I would like to use as best as I can. However the space I have left over is only (w,h,l) 20x18x52cm. I saw the following drawer on ikea's website and this was as far as I came. The problem with the product is, that it is 5cm too long. I considered cutting it  and gluing it back together but this would mean less structural integrity, wouldn't be nice to look at and hard to pull out.[image: drawer]

Of course there are a number of other drawers e.g. made of metal, but none of my dimensions. The material doesn't really matter, however I would like to have metal because its easier to pull out. I also thought about a ground mounted drawer, but I couldn't really find anything. Here you can see the space which I would like to use better (bottom left corner), maybe you have any ideas of buying or doing something on my own for low price (< 30 dollar or so)
[image]

Comment: It would also have to clear the cabinet door which sticks out because of the hinges.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the left bottom corner not the right one

Comment: Build one out of wood (or plywood) to the exact size you need and mount it on a drawer slide. I'd think YouTube would be full of tutorials, etc.

Comment: @GregNickoloff I thought about this one. Problem is that you only can buy drawer slides in a pack of 2 (which is quite expensive). However the plywood wouldn't cost anything... Do you know, where I can get full-extension drawer slides with soft close or how much they will cost approx.? And is it hard to mount a drawer?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @Wovise -  A quick "google" shows drawer slide sets available for less than $5. You won't need "heavy duty" or top-of-the-line for this project. You could use the extra one to make a similar drawer/box for the other side of the cabinet or for your bathroom cupboard.

Comment: Mhh okay, thank you. I'll consider building it myself. I assume that I won't find anything that I'm looking for...